# OAuth2 from C# Error 405 when POSTing

Tags: google-oauth

I am using Picasa's implementation of OAuth2 from C#. When I get to the step where I need to do a POST to oauth2/v3/token, I get a method not permitted error. I am using the following URL to POST to."https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v3/token". Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: When I remove the "/v3" part of the URL, I get a "401 unauthorized" message back. Maybe this is progress?

Comment: Can you show the code & parameters you pass as part of the POST?

Comment: When I use the following URL in the POST, I get the following response ...

Comment: From the URL https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token I get the response "{"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."}". My presumption here is that something needs to change in the Developers Console, but, I can't figure out what needs to change. Help! Thanks, JB

Comment: Additionally, here is the "scope" string that I am using "profile+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://picasaweb.google.com/data/"       Thanks, JB

Comment: scopes should be separated by spaces;  when sending them in the authorization request the spaces should be URL encoded to %20 's

Comment: I recommend using https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ if you want to learn how these requests work, and what params and headers need to be set, in an interactive way. NB the OAuth Playground still uses the old token endpoint, but the same methods will work on the new endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

The correct token endpoint is

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token
```

NB. **www.googleapis.com** is the host, not the **accounts.google.com** from your question.

To Hans Z's point, `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` is an older version of the endpoint, which is no longer preferred.  The current endpoint can always be found from Google's OpenID Connect [discovery document](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect#discovery).

Answer (score 0):

The old token endpoint for Google OAuth is `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`.

Comment: It used to be that, but has recently changed, see my answer.

Comment: You're right, although it should be noted that Discovery is OpenID Connect specific and not part of OAuth 2.0 (yet) so OAuth 2.0 endpoints could be different from OpenID Connect endpoints. But the Google Docs at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer also contain the new endpoint so it confirms your point.